# Enunciate Maven Plugin Error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for `JakartaResourceMethodSignature` When Upgrading from 2.13.3 to 2.14.0

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, maven, enunciate

I'm encountering an issue with the Enunciate Maven plugin while trying to generate documentation for my Java project. I recently upgraded the Enunciate Maven Plugin from version 2.13.3 to 2.14.0, and when running the `enunciate:docs` goal, I get the following error message:

```xml
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.14.0:docs (default) on project EnunciateDocs: Error invoking Enunciate.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/webcohesion/enunciate/metadata/rs/JakartaResourceMethodSignature
```

My project is a Java application with JAX-RS (Jakarta API) annotations.
I've upgraded the Enunciate Maven Plugin from version 2.13.3 to 2.14.0.

POM Configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Enunciate Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.webcohesion.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>enunciate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>docs</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- the directory where to put the docs -->
                        <docsDir>./docs</docsDir>
                        <configFile>./enunciate.xml</configFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```